# combining data elements from two html forms is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I am trying to combine data from two HTML forms and then post it as a single form which is working fine except that some elements are not being copied from one form to the other. I have defined the following javascript function to combine form elements:

```
var form = document.forms['auth_form'];
    var issuedata = window.opener.document.getElementById('Create').elements;
     for (var i = 0; i < issuedata.length; i++) {
         var data = issuedata[i];
         alert(data.innerHTML);
         if(data.type !== "submit")
         form.appendChild(data);     
     }
```

### Actual files

This is the first form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
var childWindow = null;
function child_open() {

    childWindow = window.open('new.html', "_blank",
            "resizable=no,width=600, height=280,top=200,left=200");

}
function parent_disable() {
    if (childWindow && !childWindow.closed)
        childWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onclick="parent_disable();">
<input type="button" value="Create Jira Ticket" onclick="child_open()" />
<form name="auth_form" id="Create" method="post">
        <input name="bug_status" value="NEW" type="hidden">
        <input name="rep_platform" value="All" type="hidden">
        <input name="component" value="AFAS" type="hidden">
        <input name="bug_severity" value="Beeper Call" type="hidden"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="comment" value="hello hi"><br>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is second form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
 var count = 0;
 function submit_and_close() {
  var form = document.forms['auth_form'];
  var issuedata = window.opener.document.getElementById('Create').elements;
   for (var i = 0; i < issuedata.length; i++) {
    var data = issuedata[i];
    alert(data.innerHTML);
    if(data.type !== "submit")
    form.appendChild(data);  
         }
   
   alert(form.innerHTML);

  form.submit();
  // close the window after form submission is complete.
  var docLoaded = setInterval(function() {

   if (document.readyState !== "complete") {

    return;
   }
   clearInterval(docLoaded);
   //window.close();
  }, 30);

 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div id="dialog" title="JIRA Dialog">
   <h1>JIRA Credentials</h1>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div>
  <form name="auth_form" id="auth_form" method="post">
   <label> User Name: </label> <input type="text" name="username"><br>
   <label> Password: </label> <input type="password" name="password"><br>
   <input type="button" value="Log In" onclick="submit_and_close()">
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For example I am not able to see the following elements being copied over from 'Create' form to 'auth_form' in second html page.

```
<input name="rep_platform" value="All" type="hidden">
<input name="bug_severity" value="Beeper Call" type="hidden"/>
```

Even after spending sometime debugging, I am not able to figure out why some elements are being succesfully copied while others not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.elements` returns a live collection of elements. When you append an element from the collection, it gets removed from the collection, so your index `i` into the collection get out of sync, and therefore every other element gets skipped.

Instead, just append the first element from the collection until the collection is empty. (Just detach the submit button element when it is encountered). Alternatively, loop through the collection from last to first rather than first to last.

---

<sub>(querySelectorAll() works because it returns a static collection, rather than a live one.)</sub>

Comment: okay so how do I append first element from collection? I thought that's what I was doing by looping over and whichever comes first, I appended it to the form.

Comment: Now I see what you meant by appending first element. in the loop I only utilize index 0 and it works because collection is shrinking by 1 already.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your second form from ...

```
var issuedata = window.opener.document.getElementById('Create').elements;
```

to

```
var issuedata = window.opener.document.querySelectorAll('input[name]');
```

... and replace all `innerHTML` with `outerHTML`

Comment: that does not pick up any element from create form

Comment: glad to hear that :)